# Python syntaxerror with for

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, syntax, syntax-error

It's my first post here, i've started python only a week ago and i have a problem when i run the code.
Here is the code:

```
try:
    sauce= urlib.request.urlopen('https://www.instagram.com/p/'+msg('text').read(),
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'html.parser')
    for item in soup.find_all('span', 'webtitleclass'):
        print(item)


except urlib.error.HTTPError as err:
```

Then obviously the code continues, but the problem is that it finds an error at the beginning of `for`, a syntaxerror. I've tried to add commas and other things but it doesn't change.

Where the syntax error is?
Thanks a lot

Comment: `try` requires `except` or `finally` and `for` requires a colon and some code in the block.

Comment: yes there were them, i've updated the question with the other part of the code

Comment: @eNc thanks. what's the error?

Comment: Mismatched parentheses on `sauce = ` line

Comment: @leoleo please check out the guidelines (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on posting. In particular the link entitled 'how to debug small programs' will be particularly useful to you.

Comment: Check the parentheses, 2nd line has 3 `(` and 2 `)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix the closed parenthesis and fill in the `except`:

```py
try:
    sauce = urlib.request.urlopen('https://www.instagram.com/p/'+msg('text').read())
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'html.parser')
    for item in soup.find_all('span', 'webtitleclass'):
        print(item)


except urlib.error.HTTPError as err:
    print(err)
```

Comment: thanks! I have accepted the answer! Can't figure out why does Visual Studio say that msg is not defined since i have imported telepot

Answer (score 0):

Welcome! The problem you encountered is not in the `for` keyword at all but it should be here

```py
sauce= urlib.request.urlopen('https://www.instagram.com/p/'+msg('text').read(),
```

How do I know? Because there is an unbalanced parenthesis. You are most likely encountering a `SyntaxError: unexpected keyword for` and this is a very old problem.

Turns out that the python parser transforms the source code that you have written in a tree form but sometimes things are a little unexpected, consider this.

```py
spam = []
some_function(spam)
#
some_function([])
```

They are the same but the parser encounters two different things, the first is
an identifier while the second is an list expression.

So what is happening is that sometimes the parser will have to switch to a different context; in your case is trying to figure out the arguments to the function `rlib.request.urlopen` but it encounters a `for` keyword that does not belong there at all!

Why does it not warn me before! I understand it is confusing for you but this is kind of a hard problem to solve and the python developers have put some more consideration in "forgiveness" so you might get some strange syntax error.

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation and for your kindness, now it's more clear!